# Compiling all cpp files under a directory recursivelyt

Tags: android, makefile

I am writing a make file for compiling jni code in Android.
I would like to be able to compile all cpp files that reside under specific folder, recursively.

How can i do that?
I tried playing with the wildcard command, but did not get to the result i need.

Comment: Are you familiar with `find`?

Answer (score 0):

The Android make system has a gmake macro for handling this.  Please see the documentation `doc\ANDROID-MK.html` in the NDK.  Here is an extract:

```
all-subdir-makefiles
  Returns a list of Android.mk located in all sub-directories of
  the current 'my-dir' path. For example, consider the following
  hierarchy:

    sources/foo/Android.mk
    sources/foo/lib1/Android.mk
    sources/foo/lib2/Android.mk

  If sources/foo/Android.mk contains the single line:

    include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)

  Then it will include automatically sources/foo/lib1/Android.mk and
  sources/foo/lib2/Android.mk

  This function can be used to provide deep-nested source directory
  hierarchies to the build system. Note that by default, the NDK
  will only look for files in sources/*/Android.mk
```